# Strange packages inside jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I packed my code to a `.jar` file with `gradle` task `jar`,

```
task packageTest(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'mymainPackage.test.main.MainApplication'   }

    from(sourceSets.main.output) {
        include "mymainPackage/test/**"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }


    version = "1.0"
    baseName = "Test"
}
```

and i got a `google` package which i don't have inside my code at all.

[image]

Can someone explain from where this package came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem,
when i packed the dependencies to my jar, there was one dependency that used with a some  `google` api, so it packed it to the `jar`

because I Packed all my dependencies :

```
from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```